# Installing php-module using port on osx lion

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, port, php-extension

I am trying install `php5-intl` on my osx lion.

I did install also Xcode.

When I run the command to install the module I get the following message.

```
> sudo port install php5-intl
--->  Computing dependencies for php5-intl
--->  Cleaning php5-intl

> locate *intl*|grep so\$
/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so

> sudo apachectl restart
```

My question is:

Is the php5-intl module installed and ready to be used in my apache?

P.S.:
If I look to my phpinfo() I don't see any reference to php-intl. Is it normal?

---

If I run

```
> php -m | grep intl
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
intl
```

Then If I try to use it in Synfony2 I get the following error:

```
The Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubLocale::getDisplayLanguage() is not implemented. 
Please install the 'intl' extension for full localisation capabilities
```

If I look to my phpinfo, no trace of php5-intl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not listed in `phpinfo()` (or `php -m` on the command line) then no, the module isn't enabled.

If I were you I'd get this working on the command line first, since if I remember right Port uses it's own version of PHP (and Apache?), which could cause confusion.

You'll need to enable the module with `extension=php5-intl.so` in your php.ini file, after adding that `php -m` should include `intl`, and you know the extension is working on the command line.

**Edit:**

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

This sounds like you maybe have the module enabled twice, though I don't think that's necessarily your problem.

Try running a simple command line script that calls an `intl` function, it sounds to me like it's enabled for the command line but not for apache.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually it seems to be installed but when I try to use it in Symfony2 I get an error. please look to my question because I added more text.

Comment: So probably as you said it is enabled for the command line but not for apache... how can I fix this problem? thanks

Comment: Ok you are right, if I try to run `php test.php` using `IntlDateFormatter` it works...but from apache it does not.  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function datefmt_create() `Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did open another question related to my problem. [It works from command line but not from apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869537/installing-php-module-using-port-on-osx-lion-it-works-from-command-line-but-not)