# Apache and two versions of php on osx-lion

Tags: php, apache, osx-lion, port

I have to version of PHP installed on my lion osx

```
/opt/local/bin/php (5.3.12)
/usr/bin/php (5.3.10)
```

When I try to install php modules using `port`, it refers to `/opt/local/bin/php (5.3.12)`

But when I start the web server the apache is using `/usr/bin/php` because if I look to the `phpinfo` on the apache webserver it tells me `PHP Version 5.3.10`.

How can I fix this issue?
My goal is to install php-modules using `port` which affects the `php` used by apache.

Comment: Are both PHP directory locations included in the PATH?

Comment: @Steve yes! `echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is using neither of those locations, in fact -- if you haven't changed the configuration, it's using the PHP module at `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. If the Macports install created an analogous module under `/opt` somewhere, you'll need to edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to point to the new location; if it didn't, you'll need to get it to make you one.

Comment: Actually I get another problem for which I opened another question [cURL error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878271/curl-error-ssl-peer-certificate-or-ssh-remote-key-was-not-ok)