# cURL error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: macos, apache, curl, symfony, certificate

Using `Symfony2` on my `osx-lion` I get the following error:

```
cURL error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

The error is quite strange for me, 
because if I try to use the `libphp5.so` which point to
`/usr/bin/php` it works.

If I try to change the `libphp5.so` in order to use the `/opt/local/bin/php` I get the following error

```
cURL error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

How can I fix the issue using `/opt/local/bin/php`?

Thanks

For more details I did attach the pic of log message.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the message? SSL peer certificate != SSH peer certificate.

Comment: @EJP I updated my question adding the image of the log message.

Comment: Could you show how is your VirtualHost configuration? Seems like your certificates are configured using relative path instead of absolute path.

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro is passed so long time and I don't remember how I fixed. Sorry.